# Virtual NIC on Linux

Tags: linux, networking

I have physical network card for Internet and I want to create a virtual one on Linux.

This is my configuration on **/etc/network/interfaces**

```
# Public
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 46.40.127.45
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 46.40.127.0
        broadcast 46.40.127.255
        gateway 46.40.127.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
        dns-search com

# Private
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.10.10.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

This is what I've got when I **/etc/init.d/networking restart**

```
Cannot find device "eth1"
Failed to bring up eth1.
```

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "a virtual one"? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to specify which hardware interface it connects to.

Try this,

```
# Public
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 46.40.127.45
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 46.40.127.0
        broadcast 46.40.127.255
        gateway 46.40.127.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
        dns-search com

# Private
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
        address 10.10.10.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Details can be found [here](http://www.nusuni.com/2011/09/how-to-add-virtual-network-interfaces-to-debianubuntu/)